# Send an object with iOS Game Center Challenge?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, game-center, sprite-kit

I am developing an iOS game in which the player builds an object and completes a timed challenge with that object.  I want to use Game Center to allow the player to be able to challenge his friends to beat the time using the same player built object.  The time part of the challenge is easy, but how can I send the player built object with the challenge?  I know that you can send objects if the players are involved in a match, but a match doesn't really fit what I am trying to do.  If the object could be sent with the challenge as an NSDictionary (or other object), that would be the best.  Is this possible?  And if so, how?

Comment: As Bram De Geyter has indicated, if you can pack the player build object's data into an 64 bit unsigned integer (context property of the score), then you can do this easily, otherwise you'd need to use your own server for storage  in which case the context would hold the id for your server stored object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two options for implementing this:

#### Using Score contexts

You implement [leaderboards](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html) into your Game Center game and use the challenge completion time as your score. Your GKScore object has a `context` property that you can use to transmit a reference to your object. The [`context` property](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKScore/context) is an integer value. You will need to implement your own server to store the actual object, or use a backend-as-a-service, like [Parse](http://parse.com).

When you issue a `GKScoreChallenge`, the other player can read the `score` property, retrieve the `context` and then contact your server to retrieve the object and set up his game to try and beat the challenge.

#### Using Turn-Based Matches

If you really don't want to set up your own server, you could use turn-based matches, but it has limitations. When a player builds an object, you create a turn-based match. Here, storing the object is easy using the `matchData` property of your `GKTurnBasedMatch` object. Challenging a friend would then consist of an invitation to join this particular turn-based match.

The biggest problem is that you can only challenge 16 friends (the maximum number of players in a match) for one of your player-built objects, and that your friends have to take turns.

The limitation of the number of players you could solve by creating more matches with the same game data.

Having to wait for one friend to take a turn, you could solve by setting the turn timeout rather low (not sure if there are limitations to how low), so it feels like there are no turns. Or you could use the exchange system to pass turns to somebody who is done playing before his turn actually starts.

Comment: I was afraid that this was the case.  I was just hoping to avoid it!  Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is probably something like [Turn-Based Matches](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html).

Comment: Yes, I could use a match to accomplish my task and I know I could do it that way, but it's not really a match.  A challenge fits the concept of the game much better and it would be simpler and cleaner if I could send the object with the challenge.